# For a Front end access user interface connected to a backend SQL server, do I create new queries for tables in the SQL server or Access frontend?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am a new database intern working with a access front end and SQL server backend database.  The database was custom made for the company.  One of my assignments is to take scripts and apply them to make four new tables.  I am aware that I need to make a new query for each new table but I don't know if I should make the query in SQL server management studio or the frontend access program.  I have tried copying and pasting the given scripts into  a new query in access but I get an error message "invalid SQL statement expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT'...".  I decided to try to break done the program a little bit and tested the first line

`IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id =OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo] .[FK_tblInstrumentInterfaceLog_tlkpInstrument]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblInstrumentInterfaceLog]'))`

but the same error message keeps popping up.  I even tried just `SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys`, and I got the error message "could not find file...".  I am very much a beginner and any guidance would be appreciated.Basically am I supposed to be applying these scripts the server SQL database or on the front end access program?

Comment: Are you sure the front end and back end are talking to each other? Go into the Access front end and try opening every linked table.  Can you open them all?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a pass-through query? i.e. not just a select query. Access needs to know where to send the query and since you are using TSQL not Access SQL this needs to be executed on the server.

[image]

Normally when you query a linked table the information of how to get the data (the connection string) is tied to the table. But for this kind of query you'll probably need to tell Access explicitly. Unless you are using an ADP/ADE, then the connection info travels with the program not the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you use SQL management studio (SSMS) to create and run those scripts. So the general accepted approach here is such scripts will not be placed in the front end. As noted such scripts if for some reason must be placed in the front end, then you have to create them as pass-though, but EVEN in this case you want to use the SSMS to create such quires.

So the answer here is you create the new scripts and make table queries in the back end, or in this case using the SQL server management studio.

The syntax checking, query editor etc. in recent versions of SSMS now has auto-complete etc. and you can test/write/update those scripts in SQL server. Once you have such a query or even several of them, then the resulting “several” statements can be pasted into a front end query that been created as pass-though. If you do not use a pass-though query, then you are creating and using and assuming client side SQL (JET (now called ACE)).

The client side has it own version of SQL syntax, and it is NOT 100% compatible with the SERVER SIDE. If you writing SQL in the client that is NOT pass though, then you using a linked table to SQL server. These linked tables thus will use local (JET/ACE) based SQL queries. The ODBC driver thus translates this SQL into server side compatible syntax. However the JET/ACE sql syntax is very limited when compared to SQL server and no server side commands exist in this SQL syntax for the client data engine (JET/ACE)

So for many quires, you will and can simply build such queries using the Access query builder.

However for SQL that needs to run 100% server side then such quires has to be setup as pass-though and are in most cased built + tested using SSMS.